# Error while starting my script, SyntaxError: unknown command: VAR, line: 1 (Error code: -910)

Tags: imacros

I'm new to Imacros, I know how to use it very well but I'm new to coding so It's my first script.
I'm gettig this error while starting it.

`SyntaxError: unknown command: VAR, line: 1 (Error code: -910)`

Heere is the codes.

```js
var macroStart;
macroStart ="CODE:";
macroStart +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macroStart +="SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 1" + ="\n";
macroStart +="SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1" + "\n";
macroStart +="SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 8" + "\n";
macroStart +="SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST" + "\n";
macroStart +="SET !TIMEOUT_MACRO 8" + "\n";
macroStart +="TAB T=1" + "\n";
macroStart +="WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macroStart +="TAG POST=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:LIKE" + "\n";
macroStart +="TAB T=2" + "\n";
macroStart += " FRAME F=0" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAG POST=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID;timelineHeadlineLikeButton" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAB T=2" + "\n";
macroStart += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAB T=1" 
macroStart += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "n"\
macroStart +="WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Like" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAB T-2" + "\n";
macroStart += "FRAME F=0" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAG POST=1 TYPE=LABEL ATTR=ID;timelineHeadlineLikeButton" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAB T=1" + "\n";
macroStart += "TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS" + "n"\
macroStart += "WAIT SECONDS=1" + "n"\


macroStart += "VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX" + "\n"
macroStart +="TAB T=1" + "/n";
macroStart +="URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/mohamed.nasser.37017794" + "\n";
macroStart +="WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macroStart +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT ATTR=VALUE:Hacker" + "\n";
macroStart +="WAIT SECONDS=1" + "\n";
macroStart +="TAB T=1" + "/n";


var 1=0;
var n=prompt ("Facebook Crack PASSWORD by SCORPION HACKER.",5000)

for (i=1; i <= n; i++)
(
   iimPlay("CODE:"+"URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/")
   iimPlay(macroStart,25)
   iimDisplay("Current loop is: "+i")
   iimDisplay("New Page")
)
```

Please help me I'm trying to start it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you pasted the JS code inside .iim file. Make sure the file extension is .js